# mongodb geospacial query : $centerSphere not giving good result

Tags: mongodb

I have a db with geodata (lng,lat) from Europe.
I'm trying to do a geospatial query to get all element within a circle.

So, i create a GeoJSON field, and a 2dsphere index on it. 
This look like that :

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("56c3484612aeb853a83ec336"), 
  "defaultLabel" : "Zoo de Mulhouse", 
  "weight" : NumberInt(1), 
  "country" : "FR", 
  "loc" : {
    "type" : "Point", 
    "coordinates" : [
      47.731673, 
      7.347819
    ]
  }
}
```

and `db.myCollection.createIndex({"loc":"2dsphere"});`

So far, so good. 
But then i tried some queries to check. 
I took a point at ~1,12 km (1120m) from the data, and did a request with a radius of 1200m.

```
db.poi.find({loc:
             {$geoWithin:
               {$centerSphere:[
                 [47.728593,7.333486],
                 1200 / 6378100]        // radius of earth ~6378.1Km
               }
             }
           })
```

I got no result. 
With the same request, i have to put about 1650m to get the result.
Obviously, this is not acceptable.

So, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem : coordinates were stored as [lat,lgn] in my legacy, and i didn't check before create my GeoJSON, so it was in the wrong order.